# Match one table and map value to other in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes:
df1:

```
LT     route_1 c2
PM/2     120   44
PM/52    110   49
PM/522   103   51
PM/522   103   51
PM/24    105   48
PM/536   109   67
PM/536   109   67
PM/5356  112   144
```

df2:

```
LT       W_ID 
PM/2     120.0
PM/52    110.0
PM/522   103.0
PM/522   103.0
PM/24    105.0
PM/536   109.0
PM/536   109.0
PM/5356  112.0
```

I need to map W_ID from df2 into route_1 from df1, to be clear, replace, but LT from one table need to match LT from another table. 
Desired output:

```
LT     route_1   c2
PM/2     120.0   44
PM/52    110.0   49
PM/522   103.0   51
PM/522   103.0   51
PM/24    105.0   48
PM/536   109.0   67
PM/536   109.0   67
PM/5356  112.0   144
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) should work:

```
df1['route_1'] = df1['LT'].map(df2.set_index('LT')['W_ID'])
```

Unfortunately not:

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

EDIT:

Problem is with `duplicates` in `LT` column. Solution is add helper column by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for unique `left join` by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('LT').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('LT').cumcount()
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['LT','g'], how='left')
print (df)
        LT  route_1   c2  g   W_ID
0     PM/2      120   44  0  120.0
1    PM/52      110   49  0  110.0
2   PM/522      103   51  0  103.0
3   PM/522      103   51  1  103.0
4    PM/24      105   48  0  105.0
5   PM/536      109   67  0  109.0
6   PM/536      109   67  1  109.0
7  PM/5356      112  144  0  112.0

df1['route_1'] = df['W_ID']
df1.drop('g', axis=1, inplace=True)
print (df1)
        LT  route_1   c2
0     PM/2    120.0   44
1    PM/52    110.0   49
2   PM/522    103.0   51
3   PM/522    103.0   51
4    PM/24    105.0   48
5   PM/536    109.0   67
6   PM/536    109.0   67
7  PM/5356    112.0  144
```

Similar solution:

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('LT').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('LT').cumcount()
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['LT','g'], how='left')
       .drop(['g', 'route_1'], axis=1)
       .rename(columns={'W_ID':'route_1'})
       .reindex_axis(['LT', 'route_1', 'c2'], axis=1)
print (df)
        LT  route_1   c2
0     PM/2    120.0   44
1    PM/52    110.0   49
2   PM/522    103.0   51
3   PM/522    103.0   51
4    PM/24    105.0   48
5   PM/536    109.0   67
6   PM/536    109.0   67
7  PM/5356    112.0  144
```

Comment: I think that's a good way, but I got this error: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects